# Keeping a subscription open in a singletion

Tags: rx-java, storio

I have a singleton that keeps track of the logged in user. I have a `getInstance()` method that fetches the user from the database if `instance` is null. My question is if it is ok to keep the subscription open so that any updates to the database will automatically update the `instance` variable.

Here is what my class looks like:

```
public class CurrentUser {

private static User instance;

private CurrentUser(){
    //Singleton
}

public static void init(){
    getCurrentuserFromDatabase();
}

public static User getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        getCurrentuserFromDatabase();
    }
    return instance;
}

private static void getCurrentuserFromDatabase(){
    DatabaseModule.getStorIOSQLite()
            .get()
            .object(User.class)
            .withQuery(
                    //Select a user from the User table whose session token is not null and is not empty
                    Query.builder()
                    .table(UsersTable.TABLE)
                    .where(UsersTable.COLUMN_SESSION_TOKEN + "IS NOT NULL AND " +
                            UsersTable.COLUMN_SESSION_TOKEN + " != \"\"")
            .build())
            .prepare()
            .createObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    //user wasn't logged in
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(User user) {
                    instance = user;
                }
            });
}

}
```

Should I definitely be calling `unsubscribe` somewhere? If so where? Inside `onComplete()`?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I definitely be calling unsubscribe somewhere?

No, if you want to observe changes for this query during whole lifetime of your application process, you don't need to unsubscribe from it!

> If so where? Inside onComplete()?

There is no sense to unsubscribe from Rx `Subscription` in `onComplete()` because when you receive `onComplete()`, `Subscription` already finished and calls to `unsubscribe()` won't do anything with it.

// P.S. 
Interesting use case for StorIO!

Hope your `User` class is immutable and has correctly overridden `equals()` and `hashCode()` because it looks like that you're sharing it to all components of the app and more over any update of `users` table updates the reference to the new object, so it may affect code that already works with `user` object and then grabs new one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If not in onComplete(), how about in onNext(). I guess my question is where is the most appropriate place to unsubscribe? Also, I don't quite get what you mean in the latter half of you answer. Why do I need to make the class immutable?

Comment: Well, if you unsubscribe in `onNext()` then you won't receive any updates.

Comment: Oh wait, you're filling `User instance` asynchronously and may return `null` as result of `getInstance()`, well, now I'm not sure how do you want your code to work…

Comment: Yea, that makes sense. I guess I got too caught up in people telling me to make sure to unsubscribe because of context leaks but I have no such worry here.

Comment: Sorry, the code is definitely a work in progress. The idea i had was if the user logs out, the instance should be null.